# RegionMeasure works very slow for BooleanRegion

Tags: performance-tuning, syntax, boolean-computation, regions

Consider two regions:

```
reg1 = Circle[{0, 0}, 49.11899143121631`, {1.228462753563451`, 
  1.5707963267948966`}];
reg2=BooleanRegion[#1 \[Or] #2 &, {Circle[{0, 0}, 
   49.11899143121631`, {1.228462753563451`, 1.5707963267948966`}], 
  Circle[{0, 0}, 
   49.11899143121631`, {1.5707963267948966`, 1.9131299000263422`}]}];
```

I need to perform two actions: calculate the region measure, and generate `Nval` of random points belonging to the regions. My problem is that RegionMeasure works much slower in the second case:

```
2*RegionMeasure[reg1]//AbsoluteTiming
2*RegionMeasure[reg2]//AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.0001685,33.6302}

> {0.170635,33.6302}

The same problem is for RandomPoint:

```
Nval = 10;
RandomPoint[reg1, Nval]; // AbsoluteTiming
RandomPoint[reg2, Nval]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.0001329,Null}

> {0.0018795,Null}

This is a toy example. In the real case, I cannot guess whether reg2 is a single region, or a boolean region consisting of many regions (2,3, and so on). Therefore, I need a way to make `RegionMeasure[reg1]`, `RandonPoint[reg2]` work faster.

Could you please help me with this?

Comment: For the RegionMeasure portion I see a considerable speedup if I rationalize your inputs and work at arbitrary precision, e.g. `reg3 = BooleanRegion[#1 \[Or] #2 &, {Circle[{0, 0}, 49, {123/100, 157/100}], Circle[{0, 0}, 49, {157/100, 191/100}]}];`. This does not affect `RandomPoint` though. It seems to me that `Circle` is just as simple as it gets for a `Region`, whereas a Boolean region will be intrinsically more complicated. I am not sure that much can be done *in general*. Perhaps something could be done *with your specific problem*, but you did not include it.

Comment: @MarcoB : in my specific case, a code generates the intersection regions such as reg1, reg2 (this stage is pretty fast). Unfortunately, the numbers defining the segments are purely arbitrary and not always may be represented by rational numbers.

Comment: `RegionUnion` is faster than `BooleanRegion`

Comment: @BobHanlon : I defined `reg4 = RegionUnion[
  Circle[{0, 0}, 
   49.11899143121631`, {1.228462753563451`, 1.5707963267948966`}], 
  Circle[{0, 0}, 
   49.11899143121631`, {1.5707963267948966`, 1.9131299000263422`}]]` but unfortunately the timing of `RegionMeasure` is the same as for `reg2`.

Comment: @MarcoB: ah, I see, I may use Rationalize[number,dx] applied to any number inside. This may work but requires going inside BooleanRegion.